# Unable to fetch data from a custom look up field in a custom object

Tags: apex, soql

Here I am passing a String array of Id's to sentMail() method, trying to fetch data from a custom lookup field in a custom object
Here 'Enquiry__c' is the custom look up field in the custom object 'Price__c'

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String sentMail(String[] ids) {
       Price__c selectedenq = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Price__c WHERE Id in :ids][0];
       Enquiry__c en = selectedenq.Enquirer__c; //error in this line while deploying
        return en.Name;
    }
```

**Error**
Illegal assignment from Id to Enquiry__c
Is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type for `selectedenq.Enquirer__c` is `Id` which you are trying to assign to an object of type `Enquiry__c`. That is why your code failed to compile.

Also, you are missing to add the parent field in the query = `nquirer__r.Name`.

You need to query the parent field like below and then use it to return the value

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String sentMail(String[] ids) {
     return [SELECT Enquirer__r.Name FROM Price__c WHERE Id in :ids][0].Enquirer__r.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enquirer__c is an Id value, but you're trying to assign it to a record instance. Use `__r` instead:

```
Enquiry__c en = selectedenq.Enquirer__r;
```

Note that you must include the field(s) you intend to return in your query:

```
Price__c selectedenq = [SELECT Enquirer__r.Name FROM Price__c WHERE Id in :ids][0];
```

Comment: Thanks rahul and sfdcfox..